# Remove and edit attributes in a roby on rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, console, edit, destroy

So I made a mistake when generating the model.

I need to remove the "integer: string" and I want to the `movie_id` to be a `integer` not a `string`. Thanks

```
Review(id: integer, rating: integer, comment: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, user_id: integer, movie_id: string, integer: string)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command.

```
rake db:rollback
```

then go to the migration file.

remove

```
t.string    :integer
```

and update

```
t.integer   :movie_id
```

save and again run command.

```
rake db:migrate
```

You can also add another migration to do this. create a migration file. write following code in it

```
 def change
  remove_column :reviews, :integer, :string
  change_column :reviews, :movie_id, :integer
end
```

and run

```
  rake db:migragte
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write another migration file for that, in which you can remove the column you want and change the type of the other. In your new migration file write:

```
def change
   remove_column :reviews, :integer, :string
   change_column :reviews, :movie_id, :integer
end
```